# Ripe with Opportunity? Or Rife?

Tags: phrases, differences, metaphors

[The Grammarist](http://www.grammarist.com/usage/rife-ripe/) says I should use *rife with* rather than *ripe with*.

So far so good and I agree. But is there an exception for *ripe with opportunity*?

[Googlefight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=ripe%20with%20opportunities&word2=rife%20with%20opportunities) overwhelmingly prefers *ripe*, and I like the imagery of an *opportunity tree* ripe with fruit.

Which is correct: *ripe with opportunity* or *rife with opportunity*?

Comment: Having looked at the page, it seems (to me, at least) that the grammarist does endorse it (faint praise, but still...) by maintaining that an expression that talks of abundance should use "rife", leaving "ripe" for its normal role of expressing readiness.  It's unarguably more precise to use "rife" unless you pluralise "opportunities" (you wouldn't say a tree was "ripe with apple"), but I doubt that anyone will misunderstand, whichever you use, and the only snobbish behaviour I've seen over it is on that grammarian guy's page.  I think I'll give him a miss, in future.

Comment: I'm confused about the Googlefight link. If I keep hitting the "make a fight" button, it sometimes gives me opposite results. Doing just a Google search: _rife with opportunity_ = 4.4 million vs. _ripe with opportunity_ = 20 million hits.

Comment: The correct word is simply **rife**.  The google search just shows that (a) most people are idiots (b) most people on the internet are idiots. "Ripe with opportunity" does not even make sense.  You could say "the opportunity is ripe," perhaps.

Comment: The fact that "ripe with opportunity" makes so much sense is the reason that this common error exists. It's the same reason people say "just desserts so often -- people getting the dessert they deserve just makes sense and fits the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: @Joe: Given the degree of confusion over this—even on this site—maybe name-calling is not the wisest use of comment space.

Comment: @Mark Wallace: I think the grammarist is grasping at straws by finding a few (atypical) usages of "rife" in a positive sense, and I don't see how the pluralisation makes a difference - you wouldn't say a dog was *rife with flea* either. I do accept some people think *rife* makes sense, but many don't. I'm not sure how anyone could say the *ripe* version doesn't make sense. [Here](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=ripe+for+the+taking%2Cripe+for+plucking&year_start=1910&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3) are associated usages of *ripe for the taking*, and *ripe for plucking*.

Comment: @Callithu - you're right, it's not good to be rude.  Nevertheless, the internet is rife with idiots - to some extent you have to call a spade a spade.  And too, the *Jon Stewart Show* does exist, and it is constantly rude - there's a place for sarcasm. You know? And yes, it's surprising that people actually interested in English would make the pretty basic mistake of confusing rife and ripe.

Comment: @Fumble, you've hit the nail on the head.  Note that those examples are **for** phrase.  Ripe for intercourse, etc.  there are no meaningful "with" phrases involving "ripe" or "ready".  "Ready with ___" or "Ripe with ____" just does not parse.  (Perhaps, maybe, something like "Ripe with alacrity.")  Regarding your feeling that "rife" is negative .. well, it's a data point.  the  current main phrases involving rife (rife with opportunity, rife with possibility) are overwhelmingly positive.

Comment: @Alan, I am inclined to say "people who say 'just desserts' are idiots.." but Callithu would point out it is offensive :-)  A dessert is a good thing, a desert (same word as deserve) is often a bad thing.  As you say, it causes confusion - just like rife or "brought/bought".

Comment: @Joe Blow: Just to pour some more petrol on the flames, [here's](http://books.google.com/books?id=V0UVAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA84&dq=%22ripe+with%22&hl=en&ei=L0EcTqmCK4Oz8QOS2bChCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDMQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22ripe%20with%22&f=false) what looks like a 1722 usage of **ripe with expectation**. Let's face it, both words can be and *are* used with 'opportunity' - but whichever one you're used to, the other will probably grate on the ear.

Comment: @Joe:  People use the words they're used to, the words their peers use, and the words their parents and teachers used.  If that means that some use "ripe" where I believe it should be "rife", that's their choice, and extensive usage of the variant will (and has, it appears in this case) make it a part of the idiom.  Calling someone an idiot for using different (but perfectly grammatical) words to those that you would use (no matter what was considered correct 200 years ago) is not good use of language.  Play nice, eh?  It's only words.

Comment: This is by far the most exuberant response I've had to any question I've asked on StackExchange. I'm delighted by that. That Calithumpian's first cite is from a poem convinced me that the argument from grammar was not persuasive. Traditional notions of grammar or convention have rarely been a barrier to poetic artifice.

Comment: @Kevin Lawrence: Yup, you certainly can pick 'em! Is there an EL&U badge for "asked ultra-provocative question that didn't get closed as *off-topic and likely to lead to extended discussion*"? You must be a shoo-in for that one!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two words are actually unrelated.

[Rife](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rife) appears to be a native Old English word meaning "abundant" or "generous", though it is related to a similar Old Norse word.

[Ripe](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ripe) on the other hand shares a common Old English ancestry with "reap", with Germanic roots.

Obviously the concepts of there being an abundance of something and something being ready to be reaped are related, but the imagery seems to work better for "rife with" than "ripe with".  Consider:

> 1. "The region is *rife* with opportunities" = "There is an abundance of opportunities in the region."
> 2. "The region is *ripe* with opportunities" =*(?)* "The region is ready for a harvest of opportunities."

There are two reasons why I would prefer the first version.  First, it has a better sense that there really are a lot of opportunities available, as distinct from only enough to be worth harvesting.  Second, the second version requires me to think of the region as a thing that can ripen, something I wouldn't naturally do, *and* implies that I harvest not the ripe region itself, but the opportunities that are part of it.  We would normally talk of the apples being ripe, not the apple tree.

So is it correct to say "ripe with"?  If you regard the meaning of "ripe" as having drifted enough to acquire the meaning of "rife", then yes; usage trumps dictionaries.  English is rife with possibilities; however I don't think this is a ripe one.  Personally it smacks of laziness, so I'm resisting it.

Comment: The _rife has negative connotations_ thing is what originally persuaded me that _ripe with opportunities_ was more correct. But the etymology shared by @Rhodri has persuaded me that I was wrong on both counts. My biggest takeaway, though, is that both variants of the phrase will lead enough of my readers to think that I am an idiot that I am better off leaving the phrase alone. That's a shame, because I like the phrase.

Answer (score 19):

Bryan Garner has this on  **rife vs. ripe**:

> While a tree may be *rife* (=abundant) with fruit, and that fruit may be *ripe* (=fully mature), the terms are unrelated. To confuse them is a surprisingly common malapropism—e.g.:
>
> - <sup>Iowa State  . . . made an impression in Florida, *ripe* [read *rife*] with high school players coach Dan McCarney's staff would love to lure to Ames." Miller Bryce, "Worth Every Penny," *Des Moines Register*, 26 Aug. 2002, at C6</sup>
> - <sup>"The movie is *ripe* [read *rife*] with fond allusions to earlier 007 flicks." David Germain, "Top Picks for Fall Films," *Cincinnati Post*, 26 Sept. 2002, at 14.</sup>
> - <sup>"Exotic yet wholly approachable and *ripe* [read *rife*] with top-notch musicianship and infectious energy, this 'Revolution de Amor' is hard to resist." Scott D. Lewis, "CD of the Week," *Oregonian* (Portland), 30 Sept. 2002, at E1.</sup>

<sup>*Garners's Modern American Usage*</sup>

So it would appear that *rife with opportunity* is the correct phrase and *ripe* a common mistake*.

Google Books seems to support that *rife with opportunity* came first with this [1834 translation of an Italian poem](http://books.google.com/books?id=XYi8wxCyWp8C&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=%22rife%20with%20opportunities%22&f=false):

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=XYi8wxCyWp8C&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=%22rife%20with%20opportunities%22&f=false]

*Ripe with opportunities* [first appears in 1873](http://books.google.com/books?id=f_QEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA207&dq=%22ripe%20with%20opportunities*%22&hl=en&ei=wDwbTtyMJqXz0gGdndSWBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22ripe%20with%20opportunities%22&f=false), but the complete phrase was *fields are ripe with opportunities*, thus properly contextualizing the use of *ripe*.

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=f_QEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA207&dq=%22ripe+with+opportunities*%22&hl=en&ei=wDwbTtyMJqXz0gGdndSWBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22ripe%20with%20opportunities%22&f=false]

*<sup>a mistake so common, perhaps a mishearing of *rife*, that dictionaries have since reported *ripe with* as acceptable?</sup>

Comment: I don't see how showing that some people are ignorant of the difference between *ripe* and *ripe* proves that the 'correct' version of OP's 'idiom' is *rife*. The earliest *rife* I found was 1903, but *ripe* was used at least as far back as 1875. *And* it doesn't rely on co-opting a 'normally-negative' word into a positive statement. I don't like the translation, is all.

Comment: ...I also note that (as is customary), that translation relates "rife" to *negative* opportunities - for *sin, deceit, and dark example*. Hardly a good way to get a positive idiom off the ground!

Comment: This was the answer that persuaded me I was wrong to use _ripe with_ but the answer left open a tiny hope that usage may eventually trump the dictionary. Power to the people!

Comment: @Kevin Lawrence: So far as I can see, "the dictionary" simply means "Brian Garner". I'd sooner believe Google, with 268K hits for *ripe with opportunity* against only 151K for *rife with opportunities*. Garner looks like a lawyer-turned-populist/self-publicist to me. It's all hokum.

Comment: @Fumble: I refer you back to @Alan's comment up top re: _just deserts_ vs. _just desserts_. Google not only shows us nearly 3 million hits more for the incorrect phrase, it also offers to "correct" your search to the wrong phrase if you enter _just deserts_ with no quotes. Properly wielded, Google's a great tool, but I'd argue imagining it a usage authority is a misstep.

Comment: Hmm. The internet being largely a commercial medium, I'd expect quite a few eateries/confectioners for *just desserts*. But that one's irrelevant - the word *desert* used in that sense is totally unknown to most people. Just as they don't know the present tense of *wrought*. Some words just get 'frozen', and eventually only exist in stock expressions that never die. But *rife* and *ripe* aren't like that. They are known words, local newspapers notwithstanding.

Answer (score 4):

The grammarist wins; it's rife (in the "full of" sense) with opportunity.

Something that's rife with opportunity will have things that are ripe for the plucking, though.

[edit]

Both usages are perfectly grammatical, and one should avoid trying to promote grammatical rules based on the meanings of words (i.e. the "use rife for nasty things" thing) -- grammar should confine itself as much as possible to the function of the words, not their meaning.

So the answer to the OP's question is "*Use the wording you prefer, because they're both good English, and they both make sense*".  There is certainly no room for "Thou Shalt..." statements

However, I find it quite depressing that tempers and rudeness come into play, when discussing word usage, particularly in cases like this where no-one is wrong.

Being rude to someone with a smile on your face is entertaining for all, but getting hot under the collar over such trivia wastes everyone's time.

I hope it doesn't happen often, here.

Comment: QUite right Mark.  I notice you use a sentence "ripe for ...".  If you see my comment below Oke's, I can't even think of a meaningful sentence "Ripe with..."

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of a spoonerism between the sayings

1. `when the moment is ripe` - implying that the situation, if left alone for a bit, will "ripen" like a fruit.
2. `X is rife with Y` - meaning "X is very full of Y".

The way the phrase you provided is structured, `rife` would be the more correct word. However, were it me, I'd restructure it to use phrasing 1 above (and remove the spoonerism).

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was that *rife with opportunity* was gibberish, but it turns out to be at least as common as the *ripe* version I'm familiar with. I'm a Brit, and NGram seems to imply *both* forms are predominantly US usage, but the version I know seems commonplace enough to me. Here's the combined US/UK usage chart over the past 50 years from NGram (UK usage is so low it doesn't graph at all if I restrict to just that).
[image: .]

Calithumpian has unearthed an 'original?' instance in a translation made 1834, but this clearly didn't catch on for a *long* time. I believe this is because many would feel the same as me that *rife* sits uneasily with something 'positive'. *Both* forms seem to have started appearing more frequently in the late 1800s. Initially with a tendency for *rife* to be used referring to opportunities for crime and other negatives, and *ripe* to be associated with *fields*.

By the early 1900s it seems to me there are two distinct expressions doing the rounds, with any given speaker presumably massively preferring the one he's familiar with. Both expressions are somewhat flawed grammatically and/or semantically; it makes little sense to me to suggest that only one is 'valid' or 'original, and that the other is simply 'wrong'.

To me, *rife with opportunity* is strange - I'm more familiar [*This dog is **rife** with fleas*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dog%20is%20rife%20with%20fleas%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22rife%20with%20fleas%22&tbm=bks). Apparently others feel the same (there's only one instance of [***ripe*** with fleas](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dog%20is%20rife%20with%20fleas%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22ripe%20with%20fleas%22&tbm=bks) in the whole of Google Books).

I do not feel that usage for either word is significantly affected by what I imagine are a tiny number of speakers who don't know what either/both words mean.

One reason I personally favour *ripe* is that I associate it with similar expressions such as *ripe for [the] taking/plucking* (and even *plunder*, since whenever that's said it's invariably 'positive' from the speakers viewpoint).

TL;DR: Both expressions really do exist, and in my opinion can be said to be 'valid'. *Rife* sounds odd to me, but obviously not to many others.

EDIT: As I write, this answer has +5/-4 votes, which is probably the most "polarised" answer I've ever seen on ELU. Perhaps that's to do with the UK/US usage split mentioned above (['rife' wasn't common in America](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20rife&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=5&smoothing=3) until the early 1800s, and [almost all earlier British usages](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20rife&year_start=1700&year_end=1810&corpus=6&smoothing=3) are negative).

Strangely, although almost all online references give "negative" example usages for **rife**, the only one I can easily find that explicitly mentions this negative connotation is [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=rife&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=QRbxToafCuj24QTxtIHOAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=243e08cc12dff413&biw=1238&bih=857)...

> 1. (esp. of something undesirable or harmful) Of common occurrence; widespread.

Comment: If you pluralize _opportunity_ in your Ngram, _rife_ [comes out on top](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=ripe+with+opportunities%2Crife+with+opportunities&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: NGrams is interesting but not authoritative in this context. Also, as Callithumpian pointed out, the data you get out depends on the data you put in.

Comment: @MrHen: One translation that hardly made it into common parlance for many decades is hardly relevant to identifying the 'correct' version today. My NGram does show that on average, and particularly more recently, *ripe* is preferred for the singular, which is all I've ever heard. But British usage is below the NGram radar, so I guess I'd better concede that the Yanks will say what they will, in defiance of my negativity towards anything *rife*.

Comment: +1 for noting that both usages have been around for a long time.

Comment: @Fumble:  All but three of [these 19th century hits](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%22rife+with+opportunities%22&btnG=Search+Books#q=%22rife+with+opportunities%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&sa=X&ei=sygdTuqPEabi0QGIsZTGBw&ved=0CBUQpwUoAw&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=1d88c9b33e911f53&biw=1281&bih=705) are British.

Comment: @Callithumpian: That may be a significant point, actually. I was a bit thrown by the fact that NGram won't graph *any* UK usage, so I assumed all variants must be primarily US. This whole discussion would be largely settled if it could only be shown that the *rife* version is primarily UK, but without help from NGram I don't know how to pursue that.

Comment: ...apropos which I note that *rife with possibilities* is below the radar on NGram for British usage, but *very* common in US. It's starting to look as if UK is much less keen on *rife* having positive connotations.

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree with The Grammarist. Indeed, the only preposition used with *rife* is *with*, but *ripe with* is also an acceptable form. NOAD defines both adjectives thus:

> **[rife with](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rife?region=us#m_en_us1285098.002)** full of
>
> **[ripe with](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ripe?region=us#m_en_us1285283.006)** full of

As you can see, they are exact synonyms and can thus be used interchangeably.

*Rife with opportunity* is not ungrammatical, but the common idiomatic expression, however, is *ripe with opportunity*.

Comment: Oops. @Rhodri, thanks. I misread the question. I thought the Grammarist simply said *rife* always goes with *with*...didn't read well.

Comment: Oki, while "ripe with" is grammatically correct, it's hard to see  a sentence where it could be used?  "Ripe" just means: "ready". That's all it means.  I can't really see any sentence you could construct "Ripe with _ _ _".  For example "Ripe with sugar" makes no sense (would it mean "ripe because of the sugar").  "Ripe with certainty" doesn't make much sense (that would just be "certainly ripe" I suppose). The phrase "Ready with..." .. can anyone think of a sentence "Ready with X" ...?

Comment: @Joe: _Ripe_ means something more than _ready_. And my dictionary offers this usage example: _a population ripe with discontent._ But in another sense, a fruit could be _ripe with seeds_ implying that it (a) is ripe and (b) it has seeds and (c) the ripeness is somehow related to the seeds.

Comment: @Joe: when used with *with*, *ripe* takes on a whole new level of meaning. *Ripe with* does not mean *ready with*. By the way, *ready with* is a valid phrase in its own right that means *keen or quick to give* (NOAD).

Comment: Semantically I don't see a problem with either word. Or grammatically, if it comes to that. My problem is that you almost *never* find anything else described as "rife" unless it's a *bad thing*.

Comment: @MrHen, hmm, to me ripe with seeds is just - meaningless. You know what "ripe" means when discussing fruit. (ie, it is ready to eat.) I literally don't know what "ripe with seeds" means.  It sounds like an error for "rife with seeds".  @Fumble - but, the very idiom under discussion, rife with possibilities, is the most common use of rife!  For me it's quite normal to use "rife" as a positive.

Comment: @Joe Blow: You're right about *rife with possibilities* - at 219K Google hits, it's common (as is *ripe with opportunity* at 268K, and *rife with opportunities* at 151K). Usage for all three expressions has [shot up](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=rife+with+possibilities%2Cripe+with+opportunity%2Crife+with+opportunities&year_start=1860&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=10) in recent decades.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an English expert but it seems to me "rife" is the correct word to use as it stands for "unchecked" situation.

For example:
*The new land, rife with opportunities, gave the perfect place to build a new home.*

But at the same time the following sentence is also correct,

*A situation, ripe with opportunity, is a rare event, and it comes once in a lifetime or not at all.*

So I think both can be used, it just depends on how you use it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that rife, be default, carries a negative connotation.  It seems to describe overabundance, excess, or a lot of bad things.  The only time I recall having seen the word used in a positive manner is ironically.

The corpse was rife with disease.
The park was rife with noisy children.
The resort buffet was rife with delicious seafood. (ironic)

http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rife?region=us

Using "rife with opportunity" to me makes no sense, and ripe is clearly weird, I'd go with "rich with opportunity".

Comment: We are of like mind on the inappropriateness of *rife*. But per my comment against OP, the echoes of to *ripe for the taking/plucking* make *ripe* perfectly acceptable to my ear.

Comment: In the first example given by Callithumpian we see the phrase "rife with opportunity of sin, deceit and dark example" - presumedly negative influences (in the eye of the author).  Rife with opportunity (of something good) is IMO never used.

Comment: I have made that same point about the 'original' (a translation) in comments elsewhere. But clearly most other answerers here don't have a problem with *Rife with opportunities [for desirable things]*.

Comment: ...and I'm *still* getting hammered by downvotes!