# "New lease of life" vs "new lease on life"

Tags: idioms

I have encountered both forms of the idiom *new lease of life* and *new lease on life*. Is there an interesting story behind the difference?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find this question very reminiscent of the [ripe/rife with opportunities](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33720/) US/UK split on usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to set out the usage history - *new lease of life* was around first, and is [still more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new%20lease%20of%20life,new%20lease%20on%20life&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)...

[image]

...but since it's common these days to speak of *taking [out] a lease on [something]*, it's easy to see why increasing numbers of people mishear or misremember the "original", or have only ever heard the revised form anyway.

EDIT: I won't clutter up this answer with two more charts, but if you click on the link above, and toggle the corpus between *American* and *British*, you'll see that almost all *"new lease* **on** *life"* usages are American. I have no authoritative source to back me up here, but I believe this kind of minor adjustment to phrasing happens more often in US than UK usage. Probably for several reasons, but in particular I would single out the (to me, still astonishing) fact that [for one in five Americans, English is not exactly the "Mother Tongue"](http://blog.languageline.com/limited-english-proficient-census). Even though I imagine most of those 47M people would say they do in fact speak perfectly good English, it seems to me if you don't grow up in an English-speaking home (or, setting the bar higher, where everyone *only* speaks English, as did their parents), there's a far greater chance that non-standard usages will catch on if they seem more logical and thus easier to "learn").

Comment: +1 with ["authoritative](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lease) source" to back you up.

Comment: "on life" is definitely the more common of the two in the U.S.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, I more or less said that. [Here's](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new+lease+of+life%2Cnew+lease+on+life&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) the evidence from Google Books (in my first link), which clearly shows that **on** became dominant in US written usage around 1940.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I was agreeing with you.

Comment: Wow, didn't even know the "on life" variant was a thing until I saw what I thought was a typo in a TV series review and came here to find out the truth ^_^