# "Rule the Roast" and "Rule the Roost"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, popular-refrains, phrase-origin

John Ayto, *Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms* (2009) has this entry for "rule the roost":

> **rule the roost** be in complete control
>
> The original expression was *rule the roast*, which was common from the mid 16th century onwards. Although none of the early examples of its use shed any light on its source, we can surmise that it originally referred to someone being the most important person at a banquet or feast. *Rule the roost*, found from the mid 18th century, has now replaced the earlier version.

I recently came across this occurrence of "rules the roast" in Annabel Gray, [*Amaranth's Mystery*](http://books.google.com/books?id=XOYRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA544&dq=%22half+rules+the+roast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XhQaVNnFNY6ayATfo4CQBg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22half%20rules%20the%20roast%22&f=false), serialized in *Tinsley's Magazine* (December 1880):

> [A]nd the honest fellow, feebly conscious that he ought to talk, frighten, or beat Nancy into submission, but lacking the moral courage even to remonstrate, sighed, and seated himself in the corner of a Clapham omnibus, with that injured expression of countenance we frequently see imprinted on the features of gentlemen in the corners of omnibuses, whose 'worse' half **rules the roast**, goes in for brougham-hire, and gives no quarter.

This example suggests that "rule the roast" and "rule the roost" were in competing use many years before the idea of the King Chanticleer routed the idea of the King Carver in the popular imagination.

But while the OED's coverage of "rule the roast" within the entry for *roast* is quite extensive, I couldn't find any comparable coverage of "rule the roost" within the entry for *roost* (or the one for *rule*). I have these questions about the two phrases:

1. When and in what publications did instances of "rule the roost" first arise?
2. What caused the crossover in popular usage from "rule the roast" to "rule to roost"?
3. Is it still the case that "none of the early examples of its use [that is, the use of "rule the roast"] shed any light on its source"?
4. Notwithstanding the OED's decision to place its coverage of early instances of "rule the roste" and "rule the rost" under the heading "rule the roast" and to place that heading beneath its first definition of *roast* ("A piece of roast meat, or anything that is roasted for food ; a part of an animal prepared or intended for roasting"), might those early instances of "roste" and "rost" originally have been intended to signify *roost*, not *roast*?

Comment: *My* copy of OED says *In common use from **c1500** onwards* (as the original ***roost*** version), not mid-C16. [This 1562 "glossary"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pK07AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA430&dq=%22rule+the+roast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Lg4aVJTyAtDo7AbOvIHICg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22rule%20the%20roast%22&f=false) cites a 1518 usage in its definition. But the etymology/reason for the shift to ***roost*** was obviously opaque even back then.

Comment: My copy of the OED (a reprint of the 1971 edition) says of "rule the roast": "In very common use from c1530 onwards, but none of the early examples throw any light on the precise origin of the expression." I don't know what led the _Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms_ to change "very common" to "common" and "c1530" to "mid 16th century"; but perhaps, if instances of "rule the roast/roost" have been found as far back as c1500, more light may have been shed on the phrase's origin.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the idea (suggested in FumbleFingers's link and OED citation) that "roste" and "rost" might have been intended as "roost" rather than "roast" from the outset. Is that a possibility? The phrase's subsequent history might then follow the pattern of "Welsh rabbit"/"Welsh rarebit," perhaps.

Comment: ...or [*Ripe/Rife with Opportunity?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33720/ripe-with-opportunity-or-rife)

Comment: @SvenYargs - intriguing, but difficult, question.

Comment: Barchester Towers 1857 Trollop - chapter 3 - 8th paragraph = Dr Proudies chance had come to 'rule the roast'

Comment: A recent question about the usage of *rooster* in AmEng https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381211/was-rooster-originally-an-ame-or-a-bre-term

Comment: "rule the roast"....[eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)?

Comment: OK, done. This is the best I could come up with. I find the question fascinating, but perhaps my edits have killed users' interest, for which I do apologise. It's possibly the longest answer I have ever tried to write and then succeeded to post. I'll stop now... :^)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Thanks so much for your contributions to resolving the question—and also for spurring me to post the information I had been sitting on. Like you, I found the answer posted back in September 2014 to be exceedingly shallow and generally unsatisfactory; but when I tried to marshal the material I had been gathering for a comprehensive answer of my own, it ran way over the word limit and was still incomplete. Now, if nothing else, I have the comfort of knowing that the saying's origin is intriguing to someone besides me.

Answer (score 6):

Spelling of English words was consistent with Mark Twain's assertion that anyone who could only spell a given word one way was lacking in intelligence and creativity.  It was the publication of Noah Webster's dictionary that led to standardized spelling in America.

ROST is given as a variant spelling for both ROAST and ROOST.  And while the human hen rules the home. in the chicken coop, it's the ROOSTER rather than the ROASTER that is the top dog. Ooh, too many animals here.  I promise to behave in the future.)  Since there are very few lexicographers today who heard the phrase *spoken* by Englishmen in 1769, the date Oxford English Dictionary gives as the phrase's first appearance in print, we have to rely on inspired detective work and speculation.  Freud could never satisfactorily answer "What do women want?" nor can I, and we have the opportunity, denied to lexicographers, to ask questions.

1. So I refer you to Oxford English Dictionary for the earliest citations.  Shakespeare used the ROST form in King Henry VI, Part II
2. If the words DID cross over, it's because ROOST captured the fancy of the population. The lexicographers don't rule the roost, but rather Joe Sixpack (even though canned beer hadn't been invented at the time.)
3. Early sources rarely offer new insights, and what's more, there are very few new early sources being manufactured these days.  That's not true of antiques in general, so I can only assume that manufacturing antique furniture is more profitable than early sources.  Furniture buyers rule the roost!

Comment: Just to clarify, the citations for "rule the roast" in my 1985 reprint of the OED appear under this definition of _roast_: "A piece of roast meat, or anything that is roasted for food ; a part of an animal prepared or intended for roasting." So at least at that point, the OED doesn't seem to have endorsed the idea that "roste" and "rost" (the spellings in the earliest examples given for "rule the roast") meant _roost_ rather than _roast_.

Comment: Yeah, I'd always assumed that "rule the roost" referred to a rooster, and the use of the expression has always seemed consistent with that sense.

Comment: -1 because despite the tone, and self-assured voice of authority, and almost brazen confidence, the answer lacks references,  it has not proved anything at all. Only that English spelling until 19th century was crazy and unpredictable.

Comment: The meanings of ROAST and ROOST were not interchangeable, and the spelling variants for *roost* included the  following: *hrost, roest, roist, rooste,  rost, roste, roust, rowst, ruste,* and *rust*.

Answer (score 5):

As I note in a comment beneath Mari-LouA's thoughtful answer, I have for a long time been struggling to provide a definitive answer to this question. At this point, perhaps I should throw in the towel and simply note the early (but ambiguous) examples I've found, followed by earliest occurrences of the modern versions "rule the roast" and "rule the roost." Here's what I have.

---

***First occurrences of 'rule the rost/roste'***

The earliest instances I've been able to find involve the ambiguous spellings ""rule the rost" and "rule the roste." Two are from John Skelton. First, from Skelton, [*Magnyfycence*](http://books.google.com/books?id=AiVMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA251&dq=%22rule+the+roste%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sYsbVKGyFcmrigKmrIGoAw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22rule%20the%20roste%22&f=false) (1516, according to *Encyclopædia Britannica*):

> *Courtly Abusyon.* Cockes bones, I ne tell can/Which of you is the better man,/Or which of you can do most.
>
> *Crafty Conueyance.* In faith, I **rule moche of the rost**.
>
> *Clokyd Colusyon.* **Rule the roste**! Ye, thou woldest/As skante thou had no nede of me.
>
> *Crafty Conueyance.* Nede! Yes, mary, I say not nay.
>
> *Courtly Abusyon.* Cockes ha[r]te, I trowe thou wylte make a fray.

Courtly Abusyon's tendency to use "Cockes [this or that]" as an oath invites modern readers to read the *rost* as being a perch in this case, but I'm not persuaded that it is more than a coincidence that "Cockes bones" and "Cockes ha[r]te" book-end "rule the roste" in this excerpt.

From Skelton, *Colin Clout* (ca. 1518), cited in an 1871 issue of [*Notes and Queries*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ImsJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA64&dq=%22pleasure+of+me+That+ruleth+the+roste+alone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cnQTVdCgK8zkoATAiIHIBA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22pleasure%20of%20me%20That%20ruleth%20the%20roste%20alone%22&f=false):

> But at the pleasure of me/That **ruleth the roste** alone

And again from Skelton, describing Cardinal Wolsey in *Why Come Ye Nat to Courts?* (ca. 1520, cited in an 1881 issue of [*Notes and Queries*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kWcEAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA170&dq=%22He+ruleth+all+the+roste%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO4cr3g_rTAhXB0FQKHe8YAtoQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22He%20ruleth%20all%20the%20roste%22&f=false):

> He rolleth in his recordes,/ He sayeth, How saye ye my lordes?/ Is nat my reason good?/ Good euyn, good Robyn Hood!/ Some say yes, and some/Syt styll as they were dom:/ Thus thwartyng ouer thom [that is, *thumb*],/ He **ruleth all the roste**/ With braggynge and with bost;/ Born vp on euery syde/ With pompe and with pryde,/ With, trompe vp, alleluya!

That same 1881 volume of *Notes and Queries* includes a reference to *Debate of the Carpenter's Tools* (late 15th century). In the version reported in James Halliwell-Phillipps, [*A Dictionary of Archaic and Provincial Words, Obsolete Phrases, *](https://books.google.com/books?id=mKQTAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA698&dq=%22reule+the+roste%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HpETVZK6IIK6ogSuloLoDQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22reule%20the%20roste%22&f=false) (1921), the lines run as follows:

> Ye, than seyd the rewle-stone,/Mayster hath many fone:/And ye wold helpe at his nede./My mayster schuld the better spede,/But whatsoever ye brage our boste,/My mayster yet shall **reule the roste**.

The trouble with all of these early instances is that they could be read as referring to ruling the roost (the roosting-rod in a poultry house) or to ruling the roast (the meat to be carved by the person sitting at the head of the table). So the unanswered question about these early instances is whether *roste/rost* eventually resolved into *roost*, *roast*, or both.

---

***Emergence of 'rule the roast'***

The earliest instance of "rule the roast" that I've been able to find is from W.S., [*The Puritaine, or The Widdow of Watling-street*](http://books.google.com/books?id=_SkOAQAAMAAJ&pg=PT10&dq=%22rule+the+roast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AaEbVI2YOeS9igKCh4GAAw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22rule%20the%20roast%22&f=false) (1607):

> *Edmond*. So a faire riddance, my fathers layde in dust his Coffin and he is like a whole-meate-pye, and the wormes will cut him vp shortlie ; farewell old Dad, farewell. ... Why al the world knowes as long as twas his pleasure to get me, twas his duety to get for me : I know the law in that point no Atturney can gull me ; Well, my Vncle is an olde Asse, and an Admirable Cockscombe, Ile **rule the Roast** my selfe, Ile be kept vnder no more , I know what I may do well inough by my Fathers Copy : the Lawe's in mine owne hands now : nay now I know my strength, Ile be strong inough for my Mother I warrant you?

From Richard Sheldon, “[The Hereticall Rule of the Romane Faith](http://books.google.com/books?id=dhA-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA256&dq=%22rule+the+roast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=u7UbVNqlBte6ogSuiYKwCQ&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22rule%20the%20roast%22&f=false)” in The *Motives of Richard Sheldon Pr for his iust, voluntary, and free renouncing of Communion with the Bishop of Rome* (1612):

> I ask, whether the gates of hell preuailed not against this [Pope] John [10 or 11]? Who as a Baronius himself acknowledgeth, was exalted into the Apostolicall chaire, by the meanes of the impudent strumpet Theodora; with whom also he liued most impurely in the time of his Papacie (or shall I fay rather her Papacie, shee **ruling the roast**) for which cause by the Cardinall himself this John is worthily reputed for a false high Bishop, an Apostata, an Intruder, and a most iniust possessour of the Apostolicall See.

From M.N., [*Remaines Concerning Brittaine*](http://books.google.com/books?id=dhA-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA256&dq=%22rule+the+roast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=u7UbVNqlBte6ogSuiYKwCQ&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22rule%20the%20roast%22&f=false) (1629):

> *William*, Marques of Winchester, being asked how he continued of the Councell in the troublesome times of diuers Princes ; answered, *By being a Willow, and not an Oake.* Hee would also often say, that hee found great ease in this : *That I neuer sought to **rule the roast**, and to be the director of others, but always suffered my selfe to be swayed with the most and mightiest.* [The 1637 version of *Remaines Concerning Britain* repeats this anecdote, but with the word *roste* in place of *roast*.]

And from Thomas Nabbs, [*Microcosmus*](http://books.google.com/books?id=gZg0AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA134&dq=%22kitchen+;+where+I+rule+the+roast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tlseVOKzFMrCigKI5ICACg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22kitchen%20%3B%20where%20I%20rule%20the%20roast%22&f=false) (1637, in a 1780 edition):

> *Tasting.* Tasting, mine [name], sir. I am my lady’s cook, and king of the kitchen ; where I **rule the roast**, command imperiously, and am a very tyrant in my office.

---

***The first clear instances of 'rule the roost'***

In its modern spelling "rule the roost" did not definitely appear (as far as I've been able to tell) until the 1820s. From a [review of J. Bee, *A Living Picture of London for 1828*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gk8CAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA136&dq=%22mobocracy+to+rule+the+roost%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLxZby9fnTAhUS8WMKHR39CFAQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22mobocracy%20to%20rule%20the%20roost%22&f=false), in The Monthly Review (May 1828):

> But, whatever the bulk of the people may be found in any of the provincial cities, under similar circumstances, the population of London is in a superior degree ; or, say baser, if the purpose be a bad one, as rioting, or the attempts of a mobocracy to **rule the roost**. An election he considers the highest state of excitement to which the public mind can be brought.

And from Lydia Child, [*A New Flower for Children*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ik7SAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA148&dq=%22I+expect+to+rule+the+roost+here%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYlPHv9vnTAhUX2WMKHYx6CowQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%22I%20expect%20to%20rule%20the%20roost%20here%22&f=false) (1856):

> 'Sir Naked-legs,' said I [a rooster], 'it is none of your business.'
>
> 'I expect to **rule the roost** here,' said he [another rooster].
>
> 'That you may do and welcome,' said I. 'The farm is large enough for us both; and I can pick up my own grasshoppers.' I was determined not to fight the foolish little chap.

There is in fact a much earlier reported instance of "rule the roost," from Thomas Randolph, *The Muse’s Looking-Glass* (1638), but regrettably I can't find a copy of that work from the seventeenth century. Instead, it is simply reported in an 1875 edition and picked up in 1882 by A. Smythe Palmer, [*Folk-Etymology*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8AcYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA328&dq=%22rule+the+roost,+foul+princes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn45P_hPrTAhXH0FQKHVxUDBQQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%22rule%20the%20roost%2C%20foul%20princes%22&f=false), as follows:

> *Bird.* Ay, this is he we look'd for all the while!/ Scurrility, here she hath her impious throne,/ Here lies her heathenish dominion,/ In this most impious cell of corruption;/ For 'tis a purgatory, a mere limbo,/ Where the black devil and his dam Scurrility/ Do **rule the roost**, foul princes of the air!

But did Randolph originally use the spelling *roost*? In my experience subsequent editors have been all too ready to replace the ambiguous *roste* or *rost* with their preferred modern word *roast* or *roost*.

---

***Past discussions of 'roast' vs. 'roost'***

I conclude this not very satisfactory answer with citations to a few early attempts to resolve the *roast* versus *roost* question.

From Charles Richardson, [*A New Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VWxXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1641&dq=%22rules+the+rost%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zBkbVMeWJMK2iwKMr4GACg#v=onepage&q=%22rules%20the%20rost%22&f=false) (1839):

> To **rule *the roast***, (sc.) as king of the feast, orderer, purveyor, president ; or may it not be to **rule the *roost***, an expression of which every poultry-yard would supply an explanation?

Multiple "Replies" at various dates in [*Notes and Queries*](http://books.google.com/books?id=kWcEAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA170&dq=%22heere+to+rule+the+roste%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TB0bVP29CqfDiwLghIDgBQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22heere%20to%20rule%20the%20roste%22&f=false) (1881, pages 127, 169–71, 277–78, 396–97, 432–33, 477, 495, and 512) wrestle with the question. One writer notes that both *rost* (roosting pole) and *rost* (spit for cooking meat) refer to a rod, which in turn may symbolize power in a ruler’s hand. Thus: "This year sall richt and reason rule the rod." [*New Year’s Gift to Q. Mary in Evergreen*.] Another argues that Skelton uses *rost* for *roast* and *roste* for *roost*. A third argues that *rost/roste* in the phrase originally signified *rostrum*.

Some early citations in these *Notes and Queries* arguments are the ones from *Debate of the Carpenter’s Tools* [by 1500] and Skelton's *Colin Clout* [ca. 1518] cited earlier in this answer, but in the latter case given in slightly different wording: "But at the playsure of one/That **ruleth the roste** alone." (On the other hand, Skelton, "Eleanor Rumming" [unspecified date?] has "The hens run in the mashfat,/For the go to **roust**/Straight over the ale ioust." and [Author unknown?], “Lybeaus Disconus” [?] has "I here greét bost,/And fer smelle **rost**." If we could count on consistent spelling—which we can't—we might conclude that in Skelton's day *roust* = *roost* but *rost/roste* = *roast*.) Also, from a Caxton printing of *Polycronicon* [1527]: "Meotydes sente a letter to Alysaunder in this manner yf goddess wolde that the hauynge of thy bodye were euen to the coueyteyse of thy soule/ the worlde mygghte not receyue the/ whether thou knowe not that threes that growe longe tymed be **rosted** in a lytaell whyle/ than take hede and beware that thou falle not with the tree whyle thou takest to ye bowes." (However, a later reply, pointing to the original Latin and to another translation, argues that "Caxton’s *rosted* is a misprint for *rooted*." But yet another *Notes and Queries* reply observes that the 1482 Caxton printing has not *rosted* but *roted*: "whether thou knowe not that trees that grow long tyme be **roted** up in a litel while.")

Also, Hall, *Union* [1548]: "Thou, duke of Burgoyn, **ruled the rost**, and governed both king Charles ... and his whole realme." Andrew Kingesmyl, *A most Excellent and Comfortable Treatise for all such as are in any Maner of Way either troubled in Mynd or afflicted in Bodie* [1577]: "Let us not look here to **rule the roste**, but to be **rosted** rather of Rulers." N. Breton, "Countesse of Pembroke’s Love" [1592]: "Where care and sorrow, death, and deadly strife,/Doe **rule the rost**, in this accursed life." Joshua Sylvester, "Job Triumphant in His Triall" [1616(?), but quoted from 1633 edition]: Would He [the Lord] seem to smile at Good men’s stripes among?/Would he bestow upon th' Ungodly-most/Earth’s Soveraintie, and let them **rule the Rost**? ... I sate as Chief, I only **ruled the roast**,/Dwelt as a King amid an armed Hoast." Earle, *Microcosmographie* [1629]: "In the kitchin he will domineer, and **rule the roste**, in spight of his master."

One *Notes and Queries* commenter (May 14, 1881, p. 397) makes [this argument](https://books.google.com/books?id=mQo4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA397&dq=%22precisians+may+use+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP5IzdgvrTAhUHllQKHY4GCu0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22precisians%20may%20use%20one%22&f=false):

> The poultry-yard has suggested the figure "he is cock of the walk," and it seems to me that he who is in this proud position will "rule the roost" also. I have, however, generally heard that "—— rules the roast." There is room for both forms, and precisians may use one when the ruler is masculine and the other when the presiding genius is feminine. A man rules—as a rule—"the roost," his household, but in ninety-nine cases out of a hundred it is a woman who rules "the roast."

---

***Conclusions***

It seems abundantly clear that "rule the roast" (with appearances from the early 1600s forward) was popular in English before "rule the roost" (with appearances from the early 1800s forward) was. But it is also clear that "rule the rost/roste" was popular in English before versions of the expression containing either *roast* or *roost* appeared. And the early *rost/roste* instances strike me as being quite ambiguous. Indeed, it is not impossible that the popular understanding of the expression may have flipped more than once—from (in effect) "rule the rod" to "rule the roast" to "rule the roost," for example.

I haven't been able to nail down what the original sense of "rule the rost/roste" was, but I can say that the expression goes back a long way—to 1500 at least.

Comment: I would be suspicious that there was some punning involved.  My guess is that "rule the roost" (however spelled) was first, referring to the haughty manner of the dominant rooster in a chicken yard, and then "rule the roast" was punned from it (not difficult, given the spelling and, no doubt, pronunciation confusion already present) to refer to the head cook in a kitchen or some such.  But it could about as easily be the other way around.