# Was "rooster" originally an AmE or a BrE term?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, word-usage

***[Rooster](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rooster)*** is a much more common term  in AmE than in BrE, the reason, apparently is that:

> - ***[1772](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rooster&allowed_in_frame=0)***, agent noun from ***[roost](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=roost) (v.)***; earlier roost cock, c. 1600, in sense of "the roosting bird." ***Favored in the U.S. originally as a puritan alternative to cock (n.) after it had acquired the secondary sense "penis".***

***[Cock](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cock&allowed_in_frame=0)*** meaning:

> - "male chicken," is a very old term from Old English cocc "male bird," Old French coc.

while the obscene meaning:

> - Slang sense of "penis" is ***attested since 1610s*** (but compare pillicock "penis," from c. 1300).

(Etymonline)

Though roost as a verb is from the late 16th century, rooster is from the late 18th century, and, as shown in ***[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rooster%3Aeng_us_2012%2Crooster%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crooster%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crooster%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)***, it soon became more popular in AmE.

Questions:

- Was rooster originally an AmE or a BrE term?
- Is there evidence that the term was coined within the puritan communities in the U.S.?

Comment: @Dan Bron - etymonline writes "puritan alternative" in small letters.

Comment: @Josh "Puritan" is a proper noun, acting as a noun adjunct in "Puritan origin", meaning "originating in the people who are Puritans". The lowercase "puritan" is an adjective meaning "reflective of the *values* of the Puritans", which can be reflected by anyone, at any time in history. Using the noun adjunct, the capitalized version, emphasizes the people, the pilgrims who helped found America and the relevant time period, which is what I think you want?

Comment: Related, and because I was so tempted to post the first image in my answer... [*Year of the cock*](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=30184)  The article appears in Language Log (so good clean stuff here)

Comment: Here in Southwest VA if you take Shooting Creek Rd down to US 40, you will pass Haycocks, but "haycock" has been replaced by "haystack." Curiously "poppycock" survived the clean up of our language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term *rooster* is derived from the noun ***roost*** an Old English word (***hrōst***) that referred to the wooden spars of a hen-house roof. Oxford Living Dictionaries define a roost as *[a place where birds regularly settle or congregate to rest at night](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roost)*, so the roof meaning has been lost.

The precise origin of *roost* is unknown, but it is responsible for the metaphorical expression **to rule the roost**; to tyrannize over the poultry yard as a cock is wont to do. The idiom is nowadays reserved for any man or woman who makes the big decisions in any company, group or family. [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=roost&allowed_in_frame=0) claims the phrase is recorded from **1769**.

Thus a **rooster** is the bird that *roosts*, and rules over the *roost*.

> "Rooster" was originally shorthand for **"roosting bird,**" preferred by the Puritans to the double
>   entendre of the more typical "cock."
>   *[The Etymology of Chicken, Cock and Other Fowl Words](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roost)*

It's worth mentioning that the  Puritans were a group of English Reformed Protestants in the 16th and 17th century who sought to "purify" the Church of England from Roman Catholicism. Between 1629 to 1640, over 20,000 Puritans fled persecution in England to settle in the new world. They wanted to create a "nation of saints", based on virtue, [“as a city upon a hill”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puritans#Education).

As the OP correctly annotated, the slang meaning of *cock* was well established before the Puritans had began fleeing to New England.

This is only speculation on my behalf, but perhaps the Puritans were familiar with an English (bowdlerised?) term **roost-cock**. The earliest instance, according to Google Books, is dated **1754**, the following excerpt  is taken  from a Greek-English dictionary called *[Lexicon Aristophanicum: Graeco-Anglicum](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ctITAAAAQAAJ&pg=PP201&dq=Lexicon%20Aristophanicum:%20Graeco-Anglicum%20%22roost%20cock%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir2ITAmYPTAhWmAsAKHf69BHAQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=Lexicon%20Aristophanicum%3A%20Graeco-Anglicum%20%22roost%20cock%22&f=false)*

[image]

Another example of usage, this time dated **1791**, is seen in the following [biography](https://books.google.it/books?id=pxTnAAAAMAAJ&q=roost%20cock&dq=roost%20cock&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG7-GVkoPTAhXnKcAKHbRjCHgQ6AEIOTAG) entitled: *Essay on the life and character of John Lord Somers, Baron of Evesham*

> ... by the superstitious people in the neighbourhood, that the good lady, his aunt Blurton, walking with him in her hand, when a child, amongst her poultry, **a beautiful roost-cock flew upon his head**, and crowed three times with peculiar energy.

This usage seems an attempt to circumvent the vulgar meaning of *cock*, and because its author, Richard Cooksey, chose not to use the term *rooster* this seems to suggest  that the American English equivalent, dated **1772**, was either unfamiliar or completely foreign to Britons living in that period.

The following passage bats *rooster* firmly in the American ballpark, but links its coinage to Victorian values.

> **The Victorian era saw a great growth of absurd euphemisms in England, including *second wing* for the leg of a fowl, but it was in America that the thing was carried farthest.** Bartlett hints that *rooster* came into use in place of *cock* as a matter of delicacy, the latter word having acquired an indecent significance, and tells us that, at one time, even *bull* was banned as 
>   too vulgar for refined ears. In place of it the early purists used *cow-creature*, *male-cow* and even *gentleman-cow*. *Bitch*, *ram*, *buck* and *sow* went the same way, and there was a day when even *mare* was prohibited. Bache tells us that *pismire* was also banned, *antmire* being substituted for it.

[The American Language](https://archive.org/stream/americanlanguage00mencuoft#page/126/mode/2up/search/rooster) by H. L. Mencken, first printed in 1919. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._L._Mencken) informs me that the author *was an American journalist, satirist, cultural critic and scholar of American English*

Comment: Would the Downvoter please explain . I promise I won't bite. *Really!* I am genuinely interested in knowing if the answer is factually inaccurate.

Comment: The seventeenth-century Puritans disapproved of certain types of behaviour, but I never heard of them attempting to refine the English language. I believe this trend started much later, as Mari-Lou A suggests.