# Riches-to-Rags Emotion? Is there a word for when people get accustomed to a higher quality and then have to go back to less?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, emotions

Searching for a (preferably) ***single word*** or expression that describes when a person used to "better" things (in life) has to live with less.

For example: if someone gets used to fine dining/wine or other luxury lifestyle and then has to "*downgrade*" to ramen noodles.

Its a mix of ***nostalgia*** (for the old/better times), ***depression*** (nothing will ever be as good again) and ***disgust*** (at having to put up with worse quality).

Comment: This question is Primarily Opinion-based. Someone in such a situation may feel *wistful/regretful, resigned*, or *cheated/deprived*, for example. That's at least three different feelings, and I'm sure there are many more.

Comment: Well, he felt, if I recall correctly), enraged, indignant, stupefied, cheated, vengeful, challenged, confused, enlightened, then in love, more empathetic, wiser, etc. So, this is a guessing game, which is off topic here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers is there a way of getting *all* the words that could be used to describe the feeling I have requested in my question? is there a better place than english.stackexchange to request this?

Comment: how about a feeling of "has-been-ness"?

Comment: has-been-ness is a good one. however we're looking for a word that rolls off the tongue a bit better. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the verb *[humble](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/humble)*, and its participle, *humbled*

> Lower (someone) in dignity or importance:
>   *I knew he had humbled himself to ask for my help*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 1):

You could say they were (or, felt) *debased* or *demeaned* - both of which imply a loss of social standing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of situation in which people are liable to experience **disappointment, frustration, dashed hopes/expectations** and/or a **sense of defeat.**

They may feel **the rug has been pulled out from under them,** or that this wasn't **what they signed up for.**

Comment: The [**rug**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+rug+has+been+pulled%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) has been pulled from under you! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Whoops. Apparently, I was inadvertently borrowing your ELU persona.  :)

Comment: I had to check Google Books to be sure (there are thousands of instances of ***rug*** in that link, but none at all for ***rag***). I got [caught out once before](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/33721/2637), when I assumed "everybody knows" that *a dog can be **rife** with fleas*, but a promising environment has to be ***ripe** with opportunity*. Not so in America, apparently.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Nothing so fraught with complications here: just a simple typo. (Though some adventurous sleuths here might allow themselves to speculate regarding a possible connection with *toerag*. :)